# How to make array of ints in ada

Tags: ada

I am working on a project in ada that simply makes a list. However, when I try to add the variable to the list it says it is expecting a string for some reason. Here is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure hw6 is
    type i is range 0..99;
    type list is array (Integer range 0..99) of Integer;
    nums : list(0..99);

    procedure makeArray is
        num: Integer;
    begin
        Print_Line("Enter stuff");
        for index in 0..nums'Length loop
            num := Integer'Value(Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
            if num < 0 then
                exit;
            else 
                nums(index) := Integer'Value(num);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end makeArray;
begin
    makeArray;
end hw6;
```

I get an error that says

```
hw6.adb:17:54: expected type "Standard.String"
hw6.adb:17:54: found type "Standard.Integer".
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: num is an integer already ... Integer'Value(num) expects a string to turn into an integer...

Comment: Just a detail: `index` in `nums(index)` will be out-of-range when `index` is equal to 100 which is `nums'Length`. You can write `for index in nums'Range` and you don't need to worry about what the array bounds are.

Answer (score 1):

In line 13 you convert the input string into an integer value. In line 17 you try to do that a second time; but this time you apply the string-to-int conversion to an integer value. This cannot work. Omit the second convertion altogether and write

```
nums(index) := num;
```

That is what you intended to do.

The GNAT compiler produces additional error messages:
Line 6: "array type is already constrained", To remove this, write

```
nums : list;
```

Line 11:  Print_Line should be Put_Line.

Comment: Thank you for including an explanation alongside your code. That’s really useful.